# Command-line desktop notifications on on Ubuntu Lucid

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, desktop, notifications

I'm writing a shell script from which I'd like to display a desktop notification which stays in one corner of the display until the user clicks on it, and if multiple notifications are sent, then all of them are displayed and visible at the same time in one on the screen. I've tried `notify-send`, which worked perfectly on Ubuntu Hardy, but it cannot do what I need on Ubuntu Lucid. What should I use instead?

I've also tried `pynotify` (`python-notify`) and `libnotify`, but they all seem to use the same backend, which cannot do what I want by default.

I've tried

```
$ notify-send foo
```

, but it displays a notification which times out after a few second (not good), and

```
$ notify-send -t 0 foo
```

displays a notification in a window in the middle of the screen (not good). If I do

```
$ notify-send foo
$ notify-send bar
```

only one of the notifications are displayed at the same time (not good).

After some more digging I've found:

- http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/253 explains that Ubuntu changed the notification mechanism in 2008.
- `/usr/lib/notify-osd/notify-osd` is the backend binary which displays the notifications

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that `notify-osd` is the new Ubuntu notification daemon which can't do what I want, and `notification-daemon` is the one I need, the one which was the default in previous Ubuntu versions like Hardy. Here is how to install it and make it the default on Ubuntu Lucid:

```
$ sudo apt-get install notification-daemon
$ sudo perl -pi -e 's@^Exec=.*@Exec=/usr/lib/notification-daemon/notification-daemon@' /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service
$ sudo killall notify-osd
```

Optional:

```
$ sudo rm -f /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service.*
```

Now this works as intended:

```
$ notify-send -t 0 foo
```

To revert the changes run:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall notify-osd
```

Comment: How does this fix affect other apps?

Comment: All apps would send their notification to *notification-daemon*.

Comment: Multiple notifications seems not to be supported. How can I revert the changes?

Comment: For me, multiple notifications are supported on Ubuntu Lucid. To revert the changes, do a `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ...` on all packages containing all changed files. (Use `dpkg -S ...` to find out which packages contain which files.)

Comment: @pts Thanks! `$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall notify-osd` worked for me.